# RAID5 stopped randomly stopped working and now 2 drives show as (out of date)

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm, nas, file-server

I have been running this raid for a few months with new SSDs and today the raid stops working. After a restart the raid won't assemble again. All drive are fine and show as healty in SMART.

I tried assembling the raid manually but I then two drives show as possibly out of date. One drive has been "removed" from the raid for a week now. Here's the command I ran to assemble the raid again

```
root@nl-mpl-04:/home/server# mdadm --assemble --run --update=resync /dev/md127 /dev/sdl /dev/sdj /dev/sdd /dev/sdk --verbose
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md127
mdadm: /dev/sdl is identified as a member of /dev/md127, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sdj is identified as a member of /dev/md127, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdd is identified as a member of /dev/md127, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdk is identified as a member of /dev/md127, slot 3.
mdadm: added /dev/sdj to /dev/md127 as 1 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdl to /dev/md127 as 2 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdk to /dev/md127 as 3
mdadm: added /dev/sdd to /dev/md127 as 0
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md127: Input/output error
mdadm: Not enough devices to start the array.
```

```
root@nl-mpl-04:/home/server# mdadm --detail /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 4

              Name : nl-mpl-04:0  (local to host nl-mpl-04)
              UUID : 37db4c39:6e8a37f0:1285db9a:893c5b28
            Events : 7413

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8      176        -        /dev/sdl
       -       8      144        -        /dev/sdj
       -       8       48        -        /dev/sdd
       -       8      160        -        /dev/sdk
```

```
root@nl-mpl-04:/home/server# mdadm --examine /dev/sd[djkl]
/dev/sdd:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 37db4c39:6e8a37f0:1285db9a:893c5b28
           Name : nl-mpl-04:0  (local to host nl-mpl-04)
  Creation Time : Sat Aug 14 19:37:52 2021
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 937438896 (447.01 GiB 479.97 GB)
     Array Size : 1406157312 (1341.02 GiB 1439.91 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 937438208 (447.01 GiB 479.97 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=688 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : b1955b65:89b3d637:3777c78b:57097003

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Mar 17 15:52:55 2022
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 9316ac66 - correct
         Events : 2325763

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdj:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 37db4c39:6e8a37f0:1285db9a:893c5b28
           Name : nl-mpl-04:0  (local to host nl-mpl-04)
  Creation Time : Sat Aug 14 19:37:52 2021
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 937438896 (447.01 GiB 479.97 GB)
     Array Size : 1406157312 (1341.02 GiB 1439.91 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 937438208 (447.01 GiB 479.97 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=688 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 845ae401:d70cd726:65e22bb3:28c4553e

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Mar 17 15:39:55 2022
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 80e9eb7c - correct
         Events : 2325252

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdk:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 37db4c39:6e8a37f0:1285db9a:893c5b28
           Name : nl-mpl-04:0  (local to host nl-mpl-04)
  Creation Time : Sat Aug 14 19:37:52 2021
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 937438896 (447.01 GiB 479.97 GB)
     Array Size : 1406157312 (1341.02 GiB 1439.91 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 937438208 (447.01 GiB 479.97 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=688 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : f5982485:1e59fd95:d0dfb9fe:1a5837c0

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Mar 17 15:52:55 2022
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 40c00ca1 - correct
         Events : 2325763

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AA.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdl:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 37db4c39:6e8a37f0:1285db9a:893c5b28
           Name : nl-mpl-04:0  (local to host nl-mpl-04)
  Creation Time : Sat Aug 14 19:37:52 2021
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 937438896 (447.01 GiB 479.97 GB)
     Array Size : 1406157312 (1341.02 GiB 1439.91 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 937438208 (447.01 GiB 479.97 GB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=688 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 9bd67b6f:c3fdb1aa:3f1ffd8f:07062700

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sun Feb 13 23:20:11 2022
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 10b0b50e - correct
         Events : 7413

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

If anyone is able to help that would be really appreciated!

Comment: I see /dev/sdl has been out of the array for quite some time now, but /dev/sdj has not is it possible to forcefully assemble this drive with the other working ones?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it The problem was that I didn't add `--force` to the assemble command.

Here is the complete command which I used:

```
mdadm --assemble --run --update=resync --force /dev/md127 /dev/sdl /dev/sdj /dev/sdd /dev/sdk --verbose
```